# How to make a UI for Node scripts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this node script where it does an API call and receive the response. So what I want to do is to make a UI that controls when the script works. For example when I click a button (HTML) the script starts and then prints the response into a textbox. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *something* to render the HTML and send a message to your Node.js program and your Node.js program needs some way to understand that message.

The most common approach would be to write a web service (usually using [Express.js](https://expressjs.com) unless you are using React/Vue in which case [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)/[Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) become more interesting) and then communicate with it using Ajax (typically the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)). Other options would be [form submissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) or [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Less common would be to use a framework such as [Electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/) or [OpenFin](https://www.openfin.co/) to run a desktop application with an embedded HTML renderer. They then have their own APIs to communicate with the Node.js portion of the application.